# What would cause a face to be in the wrong place after rendering?

Tags: rendering

I'm using blender render. I've only been using blender a couple of weeks. In edit mode, viewport shading solid, I see all the faces in the right place. When I switch viewport shading to rendered, the some faces are in the wrong place and rotated horizontally. Is there a reason why when I view it rendered this is happening? I would like to see the faces in the same location as they are in viewport shading solid.

Edit mode-Viewport Shading- Solid. This is correct location of faces.
[image]

Object mode-Viewport Shading- Solid. This is also correct location of faces
[image]

Object mode- Viewport Shading- Rendered. Faces in wrong location. Left side of bldg is on both sides and rotated horizontally on the left side where its supposed to be.
[image]